# Curl: parse original headers when using a proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I am using curl within PHP to retrieve some content from a selection of URLs.

I am requesting the URLs via a proxy server, however if the target URL returns a 403, the response comes back as a 200 due to the proxy server responding OK.

If I use `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)`

It outputs the proxys status code and not the target URLs.

An example of a response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-luminati-ip: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
x-luminati-timeline: z2XXX0-init:0,auth:XXX,dns_resolve:27,ipc_find:97,ext_conn:13,zlum_ztun_conn:0,ztun_conn:28

HTTP/2 403 
server: XXXXX
mime-version: 1.0
content-type: text/html
content-length: 355
cache-control: max-age=86400
expires: Fri, 28 Apr 2023 20:09:48 GMT
date: Thu, 27 Apr 2023 20:09:48 GMT
xXX-im-image-origin-path: 
xXX-im-image-policy: catalogimages
xXX-im-image-density: 1
xXX-im-image-width: 1125
xXX-im-image-type: Zoom
xXX-im-region: EU
xXX-im-origin-rewrite: true
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
timing-allow-origin: *

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
 
You don't have permission to access 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Ideally I would like to extract both sets of response headers from the target URL and the proxy response.

Ive come up with this code (stole it):

```
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,
            function($curl, $header) use (&$headers)
            {
                $len = strlen($header);
                $header = explode(':', $header, 2);
                if (count($header) < 2) // ignore invalid headers
                    return $len;
                $headers[strtolower(trim($header[0]))][] = trim($header[1]);
                return $len;
            }
        );
```

Which does a good job of extracting the headers but it just grabs everything, and doesnt work with the status codes.

Is there any built in way of handling this, or any packages anyone knows of that could solve this problem, rather that writing a bug-prone parser myself?